# ¿Cómo enviar una tabla MySQL en formato JSON de PHP a JS?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

La idea es obtener la tabla entera de MySql con PHP y mandarla a JS para poder trabajarla como JSON. Esto es lo que estoy haciendo:

```
<?php
// header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8");
include("conexion_bd.php");

$arrayPreguntas=array();

$consulta = mysqli_query($conexion_bd,"SELECT * FROM pregunta");

while ($data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($consulta)){
    $arrayPreguntas=json_encode($data,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
    
    echo $arrayPreguntas;
};
?>

function consultar(){
        const peticion = new XMLHttpRequest();
        
        peticion.addEventListener("load", () => {
            respuesta = peticion.response;
            console.log(typeof respuesta)
            
            // parseado=JSON.parse(respuesta)
            // console.log(typeof parseado)
            
           document.getElementById("mostrar").innerHTML=respuesta;
        });

        peticion.open("POST", "consulta.php");
        peticion.send();
    };
```

De esta forma recibo recibo los datos de la tabla asi

{"id":"2","pregunta":"cual es la capital de Francia?","correcta":"Paris","opcion2":"Madrid","opcion3":"Ucrania","opcion4":"Buenos Aires"}{"id":"4","pregunta":"En que año fue la revolución de 1810?","correcta":"1810","opcion2":"1811","opcion3":"1815","opcion4":"1816"}{"id":"5","pregunta":"Cual es el segundo nombre de Antonio Gamurro?","correcta":"No se","opcion2":"No tiene segundo nombre","opcion3":"Antonio, igual que el primero","opcion4":"Carlos"}

Cada fila de la tabla como un objeto diferente. Y si hago

```
parseado=JSON.parse(respuesta)
```

me tira el error

```
      VM2200:1 
        
       Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token { in JSON at position 137
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Estas enviando los json de uno en uno, tal cual, sin ponerlos en un array ni separarlos por comas, cuando lo más conveniente es enviarlos todos juntos en una matriz.

Modifica esto:

```
while ($data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($consulta)){
    $arrayPreguntas=json_encode($data,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
    echo $arrayPreguntas;
};
```

por esto:

```
$arrayPreguntas = [];
while ($data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($consulta)){
    $arrayPreguntas[] = $data;
};
echo json_encode($arrayPreguntas, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```

y prueba a ver si así te funciona.

Ya nos dirás como te ha ido.

Comment: AHora siii...Funcionó perfecto! Muchas gracias!!!

Comment: Me alegro que te haya funcionado :-)  Saludos!